# LINQ GroupBy anonymous type and select timestamp that is within +/- one minute

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, group-by

I have a list of answers that i put into groups by matching the FormId then the ProductInstance and the lastly by TimeStamp like so:

```
var groups = answersForCustomerList.GroupBy(x => new { x.FormId, x.ProductInstance, x.TracingData.Timestamp });
```

which gives me groups like this:

```
FormId = {97748e5e-be41-4d53-9ef8-f0dc150e58b6}, ProductInstance = "kontot", Timestamp = {2016-12-20 16:00:00}
FormId = {87dd356b-2770-4427-89d2-7503ee80bb1c}, ProductInstance = "Lån", Timestamp = {2016-12-20 16:02:00} 
FormId = {87dd356b-2770-4427-89d2-7503ee80bb1c}, ProductInstance = "Lån", Timestamp = {2016-12-20 16:01:00} 
FormId = {97748e5e-be41-4d53-9ef8-f0dc150e58b6}, ProductInstance = "Konto", Timestamp = {2016-12-20 15:00:00}
FormId = {87dd356b-2770-4427-89d2-7503ee80bb1c}, ProductInstance = "Lån", Timestamp = {2016-12-20 15:59:00}
```

but what i need to do and cant seem to figure how is how to group timestamps that is within +/- 1 minute into the same group. So answers with the same FormId and ProductInstance but with TimeStamp 16:01:00 or 15:59:00 get in the same group as the 16:00:00 group.

Comment: 16:02:00 should go to same group, or it's new group? Also which timestamp value should be in result?

Comment: So 15:58:59 belongs to a different group than 15:59:00 even if it's +-1 minute?

Comment: Yes, 16:02:00 and 15:58:59 should go into different groups, the timestamp that should be in the result would probably be the latest one

Comment: Sorry the question might have been a bit poorly described, i have update it

Comment: You could group on the Date, Hour, and then the Minutes divided by 3.  That would group minutes 00, 01, and 02 together, then 03, 04, and 05 and so on.  Otherwise you need to to something more complex to determine what should be grouped.

Comment: What happens if you have three records: 15:58,15:59,16:00?

Comment: I hadn't really thought about how that would work, maybe i need to rethink how i approach this. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort-of get what i wanted with this:

```
 var groups = answersForCustomer
            .GroupBy(x =>
            {
                var stamp = x.TracingData.Timestamp;
                stamp = stamp.AddMinutes(-(stamp.Minute % 2));
                stamp = stamp.AddMilliseconds(-stamp.Millisecond - 1000 * stamp.Second);
                return new { stamp, x.FormId, x.ProductInstance };
            });
```

Which gives me groups with 2 minutes forward in time, thanks for all the answers!